# Numpy matrix column wise minimum value index

Tags: python, numpy

I know I can get the minimum value of a numpy matrix column-wise using:

```
my_array.min(axis=0)
```

But is there any way to efficiently get equivalent index/row instead of the values them-self? For instance:

> my_array = [[10, 2, 3], [1, 3, 10], [20, 19, 0]]

I expect to get  something like this:

> [1, 0, 2] >> location of minimum values instead of values.

Comment: You should use `np.argmin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use argmin instead

```
>>> my_array = [[10, 2, 3], [1, 3, 10], [20, 19, 0]]
>>> a=np.array(my_array)
>>> np.argmin(a, axis=0)
array([1, 0, 2])
```